# Transposing a dataframe by converting rows into multiple columns without any aggregate function

Tags: pandas, transpose

Convert the following table:

| Type | s | h |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 |
| A | 2 | 5 |
| B | 4 | 7 |
| B | 5 | 2 |

into this:

| Type | s_1 | h_1 | s_2 | h_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 2 | 5 |
| B | 4 | 7 | 5 | 2 |

Comment: Previous solutions to my other post didn't answer my question, so please look at it carefully and help me find a solution code. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, guidelines on asking questions and sharing the effort spent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case doing the `cumcount` with `groupby` get the key then we can `pivot`

```
out = df.assign(key = df.groupby('Type').cumcount()+1).pivot(index='Type',columns='key').sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
out.columns = out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
out = out.reset_index()
out
Out[581]: 
  Type  h_1  s_1  h_2  s_2
0    A    4    1    5    2
1    B    7    4    2    5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.groupby('Type').agg(list)
df[['s_1', 's_2']] = df.apply(lambda x: x['s'], axis=1, result_type='expand')
df[['h_1', 'h_2']] = df.apply(lambda x: x['h'], axis=1, result_type='expand')
df = df.drop(['s', 'h'], axis=1).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Type  s_1  s_2  h_1  h_2
0    A    1    2    4    5
1    B    4    5    7    2
```